# Encapsulate multiple properties at once using Resharper 4.0

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When using Resharper to encapsulate a class's properties, is there a way to get it to do more than one property at a time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might or might not already know this (R# does suffer from a lack of discoverability, unless you get the one-page key-shortcut page printed out), but ALT-INS opens a box which can at least mass-generate properties for fields.

Not sure if that's any use - it's not the same as a retrospective encapsulation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there such a feature out of the box.

However, you could write a RS plugin that does this. But this would be another question...